# Adding models to a List keeps giving instance of that Model when I try to print and check the value

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am fetching data from firestore nd converting to a model, then adding to a list of items of that particular model. I noticed something was wrong, then I tried to check the value  of the item in this List, I discovered they were all instances of that model class. Screen shot of the terminal is attached.

This is the code retrieving the data from Firestore.

```
    List<ItemModel> allProducts = [];

  Future<List<ItemModel>> getAllProducts() async {
    final QuerySnapshot snapshot =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Products').get();
    List<ItemModel> _allProducts = [];
    for (var doc in snapshot.docs) {
      print(doc['title']);
      _allProducts.add(ItemModel(
          description: doc['description'],
          id: doc['id'],
          imagepath: doc['imagepath'],
          price: doc['price'],
          title: doc['title'],
          amount: doc['amount']));
    }
    return _allProducts;
  }

  Future newList() async {
    print(allProducts);
    allProducts = await getAllProducts();
    print(allProducts);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    newList();
    super.initState();
  }
```

This is the data converting the document snapshot from firebase to the Item Model class.

```
    class ItemModel with ChangeNotifier {
  final String title;
  final int price;
  bool isCarted;
  final String id; // name of produce
  int amount; // amount uploader
  String description; // description of produce
  String imagepath; // image of produce
  bool isfavourited; // favorited produce

  ItemModel({
    required this.id,
    this.isCarted = false,
    required this.price,
    required this.title,
    this.amount = 1,
    required this.description,
    required this.imagepath,
    this.isfavourited = false,
  });

  factory ItemModel.fromMap(Map map) {
    return ItemModel(
      id: map['id'],
      isCarted: map['isCarted'],
      isfavourited: map['isfavourited'],
      amount: map['amount'],
      price: map['price'],
      title: map['title'],
      description: map['description'],
      imagepath: map['imagepath'],
    );
  }

  factory ItemModel.fromFirestore(
      DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot)  {
    final data = snapshot.data();
    return ItemModel(
      id: data!['id'],
      isCarted: data['isCarted'] as bool,
      isfavourited: data['isFavourited'] as bool,
      amount: data['amount'] as int,
      price: data['price'] as int,
      title: data['title'],
      description: data['description'],
      imagepath: data['imagepath'],
    );
  }
```

[image]

The picture above shows the print statement on the console. printing these snapshots values on its own shows valid texts as also seen in the picture.

Comment: try printing like `print(allProducts[0]) ` instead of just print (allProducts), also using for loop you can print all value I guess

Answer (score 0):

When you try to print a `List` of item objects in the console, it will always return the output you are receiving in your console. To print the individual values, you can either do:

```dart
for (ItemModel product in allProducts) {
  // print all data members using product.<data-member>
  print(product.title);
  print(product.price);
}
```

or, you can define a `toString()` method override in the class, which which always display the String output of the object.

```dart
class ItemModel with ChangeNotifier {
  final String title;
  final int price;
  bool isCarted;
  final String id; // name of produce
  int amount; // amount uploader
  String description; // description of produce
  String imagepath; // image of produce
  bool isfavourited; // favorited produce

  ItemModel({
    required this.id,
    this.isCarted = false,
    required this.price,
    required this.title,
    this.amount = 1,
    required this.description,
    required this.imagepath,
    this.isfavourited = false,
  });

  /// toString() override
  @override
  public String toString() {
    return 'title: $title, price: $price'; // you can add more values to be printed
  }

  factory ItemModel.fromMap(Map map) {
    return ItemModel(
      id: map['id'],
      isCarted: map['isCarted'],
      isfavourited: map['isfavourited'],
      amount: map['amount'],
      price: map['price'],
      title: map['title'],
      description: map['description'],
      imagepath: map['imagepath'],
    );
  }

  factory ItemModel.fromFirestore(
      DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot)  {
    final data = snapshot.data();
    return ItemModel(
      id: data!['id'],
      isCarted: data['isCarted'] as bool,
      isfavourited: data['isFavourited'] as bool,
      amount: data['amount'] as int,
      price: data['price'] as int,
      title: data['title'],
      description: data['description'],
      imagepath: data['imagepath'],
    );
  }
```